# latest post showing up twice on posts page

Tags: posts, categories

Can someone please help me alter my coding to eliminate my problem? I am using this line before the loop:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=3&showposts='.get_option('posts_per_page')); ?>
```

for context:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="page-wrap">

    <div id="content">

        <div class="post-wrap">

        <?php query_posts('cat=9&showposts='.get_option('posts_per_page')); ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <div <?php post_class('post') ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h2 class="blog-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <small></small>

                    <div class="entry">
                        <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
                    </div>      

                    <p class="postmetadata">Posted <?php the_time('M j Y') ?></p>   
                </div>


            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
                <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

        <?php else : ?>

            <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
            <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- .post-wrap -->

    </div><!-- #content -->
```

I believe this is what is causing my latest post to show up twice. Is there supposed to be something else along with this line??

Comment: could you post more the code? (the loop, etc) - to give it some context?

Comment: @StephenHarris I updated the question

Comment: As of version 2.1 of WP, `showposts` is deprecated in favor of `posts_per_page`. However I don't know if that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your code with the following:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query( array( 'cat' => '9', 'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' )));
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<?php query_posts('cat=9&showposts='.get_option('posts_per_page')); ?>
```

with

```
<?php query_posts('cat=9&posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page')); ?>
```

after the while loop (just after endwhile) insert

```
wp_reset_query();
```

if it does not solve the problem then try getting value of get_option('posts_per_page') to see if it is not the culprit.

If nothing solves the problem, then try @fxfutures answer.